# Blazor 8.0 nested component not rendered

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, blazor-component

I tried to create a grid component by myself. I created component called `DataTable` and another called `Column`. Here is the code for `DataTable`:

```
public partial class DataTable<TEntity> : ComponentBase
{
    // [Parameter]
    // public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }

    // [Parameter]
    // public RenderFragment Columns { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public List<IColumn<TEntity>> DataColumns { get; set; } = new List<IColumn<TEntity>>();

    public List<TEntity> Data { get; set; } = new List<TEntity>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Get data
    }

    public void AddColumn(IColumn<TEntity> column)
    {
        DataColumns.Add(column);
    }
}
```

And the `Razor` part:

```
@typeparam TEntity
@attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TEntity))]

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (IColumn<TEntity> column in DataColumns) {
                <th>A</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            foreach (TEntity entity in Data) {
                foreach (IColumn<TEntity> column in DataColumns) {
                    <td>@column.Value.Compile()(entity)</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the code for `Column`:

```
public partial class Column<TEntity, TValue> : ComponentBase, IColumn<TEntity>
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private DataTable.DataTable<TEntity> Parent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<TValue, string> Format { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Parent), "");

        Parent.AddColumn(this);

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

And in HTML I call my component in this way:

```
<DataTable TEntity="User">
    @* <Header></Header>
    <Columns>
        <Column Value="x => x.Name"></Column>
        <Column Value="x => x.Surname"></Column>
        <Column Value="x => x.LastAccess" Format="@(x => x?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))"></Column>
    </Columns> *@
    <Column Value="x => x.Name"></Column>
    <Column Value="x => x.Surname"></Column>
    <Column Value="x => x.LastAccess" Format="@(x => x?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))"></Column>
</DataTable>
```

The problem is that method `OnInitialized` in `Column` component has never fired, so my `DataColumns` property remains empty. What I'm doing wrong? As you can see I tried to move columns creation outside `Columns` fragment but without success.

Comment: Can you show the razor part for the Column component?

Comment: Razor part for the `Column` is empty. I need only properties to handle it in `DataTable` razor part. I updated question whit this part.

Comment: So maybe the component doesn't go to OnInitialized, because there is nothing to initialize.. Try to create .razor with display:hidden tag

Comment: This is expected: you  don't render the `<Columns>` anywhere in DataTable so they never get created or initialized.

Comment: Also, be clear about that commenting-out of the Columns and ChildContent.

Comment: Have a look at the QuickGrid source, they have a trick with delayed rendering to solve this problem.

Comment: But if I add a `Column` outside of `DataTable` the `OnInitialized` method is triggered. I already saw `QuickGrid`, I think you're referring to `Virtualize` tag. Correct?

Comment: @HenkHolterman anyway, this is the link to sample I followed: https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm

Comment: No, I was not talking about Virtualize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe [meziantou blog](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm) does mention and solve the problem. You seem to have omitted the 2 crucial elements that bring the columns to life:

`ChildContent` contains the columndefinitions. You have to render it to actually create the columns.

```html
<CascadingValue IsFixed="true" Value="this">@ChildContent</CascadingValue>
```

Note that the Column components do not have any markup, this will not render anything visual, it will just create the components.

But the above line will create the columns too late for the first render of the table. So you will have to immediately request a second render:

```cs
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    // The first render will instantiate the GridColumn defined in the ChildContent.
    // GridColumn calls AddColumn during its initialization. This means that until
    // the first render is completed, the columns collection is empty.
    // Calling StateHasChanged() will re-render the component,
    // so the second time it will know the columns

    StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I forgot `CascadingValue`. Now it works fine. `OnAfterRender` doesn't trigger but isn't a problem. Thank you!